# display 3 months calendar with previous and next arrows at the top using calendar library codeigniter : Issue with Previous Button

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I am using Codegniter **Calendar library** to display three months calendar in one shot (page) with previous and next buttons at the top of the page .

**My Issue :** Its working fine with "Next" button , but with "Previous" button , I am unable to "decrement the year".

i.e , Initially , on the first page , it shows calendar from [March 2019-May 2019] , on clicking "Next" button , it shows calendar from [June 2019- August 2019] : working fine.

But when you click the "Previous"  button , it shows calendar of the months [Feb 2019,Jan 2019,**March 2019**]. It should be **December 2018** instead of March 2019 .

Here is my Code:

application/controllers/Calendar_controller1.php

```
public function display($year=null,$month=null){


    if(!$year){

        $year = date('Y');

    }

    if(!$month){

        $month = date('m');
    }

    $this->load->model("cal_model1");
    $data["cur_month_calendar"] = $this->cal_model1->generate($year,$month);
    $data["cur_month1_calendar"] = $this->cal_model1->generate($year,$month+1);
    $data["cur_month2_calendar"] = $this->cal_model1->generate($year,$month+2);

    $data["year"] = $year;
    $data["nxt_month"] = $month+2;
    $data["prev_month"] = $month;


    $this->load->view("cal_view1",$data);
}


 public function build_next_display(){


    $varCurMonth = $this->input->post('month');
    $varCurYear = $this->input->post('year');
    $this->load->model("cal_model1");
     $data["nxt_month1"] = $this->cal_model1->generate($varCurYear,$varCurMonth+1);
    $data["nxt_month2"] = $this->cal_model1->generate($varCurYear,$varCurMonth+2);
    $data["nxt_month3"] = $this->cal_model1->generate($varCurYear,$varCurMonth+3);

    $data["year"] = $varCurYear;
    $data["month"] = $varCurMonth+3;

    //$this->load->view("cal_view1",$data); 

    echo json_encode($data);
} 


     public function build_prev_display(){


    $varCurMonth = $this->input->post('month');
    $varCurYear = $this->input->post('year');
    $this->load->model("cal_model1");
     $data["nxt_month1"] = $this->cal_model1->generate($varCurYear,$varCurMonth-1);
    $data["nxt_month2"] = $this->cal_model1->generate($varCurYear,$varCurMonth-2);
    $data["nxt_month3"] = $this->cal_model1->generate($varCurYear,$varCurMonth-3);

    $data["year"] = $varCurYear;
    $data["month"] = $varCurMonth-1;

    //$this->load->view("cal_view1",$data); 

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

application/models/Cal_model1.php

```
public  $conf = array();

public function __construct(){



    $this->conf = array(
                'start_day' => 'monday',
                //'show_next_prev' => true,
                //'next_prev_url' => base_url().'Calendar_Controller/display',
                'day_type' => 'short'
    );

    $this->conf['template'] = '

    {table_open}<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="calendar">{/table_open}

    {heading_row_start}<tr class="heading">{/heading_row_start}

    {heading_previous_cell}<th><a href="{previous_url}">&lt;&lt;</a></th>{/heading_previous_cell}
    {heading_title_cell}<th colspan="{colspan}">{heading}</th>{/heading_title_cell}
    {heading_next_cell}<th><a href="{next_url}">&gt;&gt;</a></th>{/heading_next_cell}

    {heading_row_end}</tr>{/heading_row_end}

    {week_row_start}<tr class="weekdays">{/week_row_start}
    {week_day_cell}<td>{week_day}</td>{/week_day_cell}
    {week_row_end}</tr>{/week_row_end}

    {cal_row_start}<tr class="days">{/cal_row_start}
    {cal_cell_start}<td class="day">{/cal_cell_start}
    {cal_cell_start_today}<td>{/cal_cell_start_today}
    {cal_cell_start_other}<td class="other-month">{/cal_cell_start_other}

    {cal_cell_content}
        <div class="day_num">{day}</div>
        <div class="content">{content}</div>
    {/cal_cell_content}
    {cal_cell_content_today}
        <div class="day_num highlight">{day}</div>
        <div class="content">{content}</div>
    {/cal_cell_content_today}

    {cal_cell_no_content}
        <div class="day_num">{day}</div>
    {/cal_cell_no_content}
    {cal_cell_no_content_today}
        <div class="day_num highlight">{day}</div>
    {/cal_cell_no_content_today}

    {cal_cell_blank}&nbsp;{/cal_cell_blank}

    {cal_cell_other}
        <div class="day_num">{day}</div>
    {/cal_cel_other}

    {cal_cell_end}</td>{/cal_cell_end}
    {cal_cell_end_today}</td>{/cal_cell_end_today}
    {cal_cell_end_other}</td>{/cal_cell_end_other}
    {cal_row_end}</tr>{/cal_row_end}




    {table_close}</table>{/table_close}
    ';



}


public function startsWith($string, $startString){

    $len = strlen($startString); 
    return (substr($string, 0, $len) === $startString); 

}


public function get_calendar_data($year,$month){

    $varMonthLen = strlen($month);
    if($varMonthLen == 1){
        $month = '0'.$month;
    }
    $this->db->select('holiday_date,holiday_name');
    $this->db->from('holiday_list');
    $this->db->where('country_id',1);
    $this->db->like('holiday_date',"$year-$month",'after');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    //print_r($this->db->last_query());exit;
    //print_r($query->result());


    $cal_data = array();
    foreach($query->result() as $row){
        $holiday_date = substr($row->holiday_date,8,2);

        $startsWithZero = $this->startsWith($holiday_date,"0");

        if($startsWithZero == true){
            $holiday_date = str_replace('0','',$holiday_date);
        }
        $cal_data[$holiday_date] = $row->holiday_name;  
    }



    return $cal_data; //Issue : 01 -09 Dates  , If you change , this to 1 -9 , it works


}


public function generate($year,$month){

    $this->load->library("calendar",$this->conf);
    $cal_data = $this->get_calendar_data($year,$month);
    //print_r($cal_data);
    return $this->calendar->generate($year,$month,$cal_data);
}
```

application/views/cal_view1.php

```js
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var year = "<?php echo $year; ?>";
var nxtMonth = "<?php echo $nxt_month; ?>";
var prevMonth = "<?php echo $prev_month; ?>";


$('.previous').click(function(){

//alert("previous");
//alert("year"+year);
//alert("month"+prevMonth);

$.ajax({
   url: "<?php echo base_url();?>Calendar_controller1/build_prev_display",
   type: "POST",
   data: {'month':prevMonth,'year':year},

   dataType: "json",
   success: function (res) {
   
 console.log(res.nxt_month1);
 $('#cur_month_calendar').html('');
 $('#cur_month_calendar').html(res.nxt_month1);
 
 $('#cur_month1_calendar').html('');
 $('#cur_month1_calendar').html(res.nxt_month2);
 
 $('#cur_month2_calendar').html('');
 $('#cur_month2_calendar').html(res.nxt_month3);
 
 year = res.year;
 prevMonth = res.month;
 
  },                   
});


});

$('.next').click(function(){

//alert("next");
//alert("year"+year);
//alert("month"+nxtMonth);



$.ajax({
   url: "<?php echo base_url();?>Calendar_controller1/build_next_display",
   type: "POST",
   data: {'month':nxtMonth,'year':year},

   dataType: "json",
   success: function (res) {
   
 console.log(res.nxt_month1);
 $('#cur_month_calendar').html('');
 $('#cur_month_calendar').html(res.nxt_month1);
 
 $('#cur_month1_calendar').html('');
 $('#cur_month1_calendar').html(res.nxt_month2);
 
 $('#cur_month2_calendar').html('');
 $('#cur_month2_calendar').html(res.nxt_month3);
 
 year = res.year;
 nxtMonth = res.month;
 
  },                   
}); 

});

</script>
```

```css
.calendar{
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:12px;
}
table.calendar{
 
 margin:auto;
 border-collapse:collapse;
}
.calendar .days td{
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 border:2px solid black;
 padding:4px;
 vertical-align:top;
 background-color:#DEF;
 
}

.calendar .days td:hover{

 background-color:#FFF;
 
}

.calendar .weekdays td{
 
 border:2px solid black;
 padding:2px;
 text-align:center;
 background-color : #C0C0C0;
}

.calendar .heading th{
 
 text-transform:uppercase;
    font-size:16px; 
 padding:10px;
 
}

.calendar .highlight{
 
 font-weight:bold;
 color:blue; 
}

.calendar .content{
    
    width: 50px;
    background-color: #bbb;
 border-radius: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
 border: 2px solid green;
    text-align: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.previous {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
 
}

.next {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="previous">&laquo; </a>
<a href="#" class="next"> &raquo;</a>

<?php //echo $calendar; ?>



<div id="cur_month_calendar">
 <?php echo $cur_month_calendar; ?>
</div>

<div id="cur_month1_calendar">
 <?php echo $cur_month1_calendar; ?>
</div>

<div id="cur_month2_calendar">
 <?php echo $cur_month2_calendar; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Basically, you need to convert the separate values for month and year into a date, then use the date functions to add or subtract 3 months, then convert back into your month and year values.

Comment: I am unable to understand your concept ... Can you help me with some examples.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should do what you want, but could be simplified. I wrote this way so you can see how dates work in PHP. For reference, take a look at [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php), [date_add](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) and [date_sub](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php).

```
public function build_next_display(){

    $varCurMonth = $this->input->post('month');
    $varCurYear = $this->input->post('year');

    $startTimeStamp = strtotime($varCurYear.'/'.$varCurMonth.'/01');
    $interval1 = new DateInterval('P0M');
    $interval2 = new DateInterval('P1M');
    $interval3 = new DateInterval('P2M');

    $Month1 = date_add( $startTimeStamp, $interval1 );
    $Month2 = date_add( $startTimeStamp, $interval2 );
    $Month3 = date_add( $startTimeStamp, $interval3 );

    $this->load->model("cal_model1");
    $data["nxt_month1"] = $this->cal_model1->generate(year($Month1),month($Month1));
    $data["nxt_month2"] = $this->cal_model1->generate(year($Month2),month($Month2));
    $data["nxt_month3"] = $this->cal_model1->generate(year($Month3),month($Month3));
    $data["year"] = year($Month1);
    $data["month"] = month($Month3);

    //$this->load->view("cal_view1",$data); 

    echo json_encode($data);
} 


public function build_prev_display(){


    $varCurMonth = $this->input->post('month');
    $varCurYear = $this->input->post('year');

    $interval1 = new DateInterval('P0M');
    $interval2 = new DateInterval('P1M');
    $interval3 = new DateInterval('P2M');

    $Month1 = date_sub( $startTimeStamp, $interval1 );
    $Month2 = date_sub( $startTimeStamp, $interval2 );
    $Month3 = date_sub( $startTimeStamp, $interval3 );

    $this->load->model("cal_model1");
    $data["nxt_month1"] = $this->cal_model1->generate(year($Month1),month($Month1));
    $data["nxt_month2"] = $this->cal_model1->generate(year($Month2),month($Month2));
    $data["nxt_month3"] = $this->cal_model1->generate(year($Month3),month($Month3));
    $data["year"] = year($Month1);
    $data["month"] = month($Month3);

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```